# Retrieving constantly updating system time in javascript

Tags: javascript, time

I want to execute a block of code every two seconds—to accomplish this, I thought the easiest way would be to retrieve the current system time as so:

```
if ((Date().getSeconds()) % 2 == 0) {
    alert("hello"); //I want to add code here!
}
```

However, my alert is not printing to the screen every two seconds. How can this be properly implemented?

Comment: Have you try https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_setinterval.asp

Comment: Aha! I have not tried that. Perhaps that is my best option...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to run a block of code every `x` seconds, you can use `setInterval`. 
Here's an example:

```
setInterval(function(){ 
  alert("Hello"); 
}, x000); // x * 1000 (in milliseconds)
```

Here's a working snippet:

```js
setInterval(function() {
  console.log("Hello");
}, 2000);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use setInterval().  This will loop every 2 seconds.

```
setInterval(function() {
    //something juicy
}, 2000);
```

Answer (score 1):

This should work for you.

```
setInterval(function() {
    //do your stuff
}, 2000)
```

However, to answer why your code is not working, because it is not in a loop.

```
runInterval(runYourCodeHere, 2);

function runInterval(callback, interval) {
  var cached = new Array(60);
  while (true) {
    var sec = new Date().getSeconds();
    if (sec === 0 && cached[0]) {
      cached = new Array(60);
    }

    if (!cached[sec] && sec % interval === 0) {
      cached[sec] = true;
      callback();
    }
  }
}

function runYourCodeHere() {
  console.log('test');
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using the setInterval() method

```
setInterval(function () {console.log('hello'); }, 2000)
```